# How to use hibernate query on two tables (join table)?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have these tables: cont(id_cont, user, pass)
                      emp(emp_id, name, cont_id_cont (fk))

> ```
> @Entity
> @Table(name = "emp", catalog = "", uniqueConstraints = {
>       @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "cont_id_cont") })
> public class Emp implements java.io.Serializable{
>   private int id_emp;
>   private ContUser contUser; 
>   private String name;
> ```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cont", catalog = "", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "pass") })
public class Cont implements java.io.Serializable{

    private int id_cont;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
private Set<Emp> empForCont = new HashSet<Emp>(0);
}
```

Now: I want this query: 
select cont.user, emp.name, emp.cont_id_cont from cont 
inner join emp on cont.id_cont= emp.cont_id_cont where cont.user = 'gbs04405';

Comment: What is the error with your query? Your query looks fine.

Comment: @Taylor you can create createQuery object then you can right simple join query and fetch the related values from the those join table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This style of accessing data is not what `ORM` is intended for. If you are using `Hibernate`, you should (usually) access data through objects. To make this work, instead of embedding SQL like constraints, define relations `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne`, and/or `@ManyToMany` between objects where necessary.

In addition, you should consider using `HQL` (or `JPQL`) instead of pure `SQL`, to achieve what you want.

---

It should be something like this:

```
SELECT e FROM Emp e JOIN e.contUser u WHERE u.user = :userstring
```

You can check [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL) for further `JPQL` syntax.